# Why is String.Format("%1s","") not returning "" but " "?

Tags: java, string

```
String.format("%1s","").equals("")); // --> return false !
String.format("%1s","").equals(" ")); // --> return true !
```

- Why is this happening ?
- Where does the space come from ?

Comment: Have you had a look through the docs of [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)?  This behavior is exactly as specified.

Comment: I actually got confused with %1$s specifier, it's indeed as specified.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The space is specified by the minimum width value `1` in the format specifier

```
String.format("%1s","").equals(" ")
                ^
```

Comment: Whao. And here I thought it was related to the order of the args passed after. Thanks

Comment: +1. Specifically, the `1` is a *width*, i.e. (from the Javadoc) "the minimum number of characters to be written to the output".

Comment: @C4stor: You're thinking of `%1$s`. The dollar sign is required after an argument index.

Comment: @C4stor Right - in many cases the number following the percent sign *is* indicating the argument index, *but only if* that index is followed by a dollar sign: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 3):

You wanted to add an argument index like this

```
String.format("%1$s", ""); //returns ""
String.format("%2$s %1$s", "a", "b"); //returns "b a"
```

Your code defined a "width"

```
String.format("%3s", ""); // returns "   ";
String.format("%3s", "a"); // returns "  a";
String.format("%-3s", "a"); // returns "a  ";
```

Read this for more info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here `%1s` is a format specifier which doesn't have any arguments. The general syntax for no argument format specifier is as follows

```
%[flags][width]conversion
```

where

> The optional **flags** is a set of characters that modify the output format. The set of valid flags depends on the conversion.

and

> The optional **width** is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.

So, `1` specifies the width and here is the description behind why you get `" "` and not `""`

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. If the length of the converted value is less than the width then the output will be padded by '  ' (\u0020') until the total number of characters equals the width. The padding is on the left by default. If the '-' flag is given, then the padding will be on the right. If the width is not specified then there is no minimum.

PS: **\u0020** is Unicode character for `Space`.

Hope this helps.